# Is it necessary to create custom video controls if you are using a video texture in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, video, three.js

I'm implementing a video texture in THREE.js, similar to this example:

[Stemkoski Video Texture Example](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Video.html)

I've noticed that the author of that example resorted to custom keyboard controls. Is that because it's not currently possible to use the native controls provided by HTML5 if you have a video texture in THREE.js?

I tried the following code in the video tag,

```
<video controls src="example_video_source"></video>
```

and although the video played correctly, no controls were present. Why? Thanks
in advance.

Comment: no one has any input on this question?

Comment: I decided to add custom controls, but hopefully someone can provide an answer at some point. Thanks.